# Unsync repository VSCODE

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have integrated GIT with VSCODE and it is useful for repositories I am actively working on.

However, I once cloned from someone whose code I cannot and do not want to change, but the program is always itching to sync it to the initial remote repository (not mine) no matter where I move it in my local directory or how many times I copy the folder and rename it.

I'm new to this so I don't know why this is happening.

How can I remove a "GIT" association from the local (copied) directory entirely?

Comment: Worked. Thank you two very much. I am somewhat new to the terminal. Note to self: Do not be afraid of the terminal! Now only the heroku remote remains. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a git repository from a remote `git` will set up references to the remote branch and name them `origin`. This is described further in the [docs for git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

You can see this when opening your console and type `git remote -v`

```sh
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/example/example.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/example/example.git (push)
```

You can edit these, either by changing url, add new remotes, or delete existing ones.

To remove the remote named `origin` you would type

```sh
$ git remote remove origin
```

Answer (score 0):

After backing up,

1. Try deleting the `.git` directory in your project, and
2. Starting a fresh `git init` from the command line in your project directory.

If you can't see the `.git` directory, it's hidden, which is normal.  Instructions to view hidden files differ per OS; or you can delete it directly from the command line.

Comment: This would remove everything though, including any history in that repository. Not sure this is what OP wants

Comment: @Patrick I wasn't sure, either.  Btw, I think you have a typo in your second code block: you want `remove` instead of `remote` twice?  I can't edit a single character, so just pointing that out.

Comment: Yepp, you're right, it should be `git remote remove <name>`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> However, I once cloned from someone whose code I cannot and do not want to change, but the program is always itching to sync it to the initial remote repository (not mine)

With [VSCode 1.48 (July 2018)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_48.md), it won't sync it anymore

See [issue 102393](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102393) and [commit 413e660](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/413e660e53049b5acc29990fbd170911fa705c84)

You will now see:

```
You don't have permissions to push to '<owner>/<repo>' on GitHub.  
Would you like to create a fork and push to it instead?
```

VSCode will propose you to [create a fork](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo) for you.